# Change name and description of a flutter web app

Tags: json, flutter, web, yaml, flutter-web

I want to publish my flutter web app. This worka fine, but if I send the link to somebody, if the messaging system "unravels" links, it shows the package name and the original description: "A new Flutter project.". I want to change this. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `pubspec.yaml`

Its in the first lines of the file:

```
name: test_project
description: A new Flutter project.
```

Comment: I understand, but if I want to change the name to something like this: Test Project, is that possible?

Comment: and I still get the same description

Comment: hm okay, depending on the operating system you want to publish, android, ios, web, you have another place to edit it. For the web app check the index.html in your web folder inside the head.

Comment: I changed the description there and in the manifest.json, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To change the description of your web app in an embed, first find `/web/index.html` in your project folder

There you need to find the meta tag that contains your app description and change its content: `<meta name="description" content="Your app description here!">`.

After doing that, build your web app with `flutter build web` in your console.

Your new website with the correct embed will be in `/build/web`.

Happy coding!